# Using hibernate for an exsisting Spring batch database

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-batch

I'm working on a batch project that uses the spring batch core library the library uses jdbcTemplate to persist jobs meta data

and i'm trying to use hibernate in order to read the data about a specific job

so far so good
I've created all the domain entities and the jpa repositoris of spring batch

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <HikariCP.version>2.4.5</HikariCP.version>
    <postgresql.version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</postgresql.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>${HikariCP.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--jackson-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**DatabaseConfiguration.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate4.Hibernate4Module;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException;
import org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Arrays;


@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.ben.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.ben.domain"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {
    private final org.slf4j.Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    private RelaxedPropertyResolver propertyResolver;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
        this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(env, "spring.datasource.");
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        log.debug("Configuring Datasource");

        if (propertyResolver.getProperty("url") == null && propertyResolver.getProperty("databaseName") == null) {
            log.error("Your database connection pool configuration is incorrect! The application" +
                            "cannot start. Please check your Spring profile, current profiles are: {}",
                    Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));

            throw new ApplicationContextException("Database connection pool is not configured correctly");
        }
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDataSourceClassName(propertyResolver.getProperty("dataSourceClassName"));
        if (propertyResolver.getProperty("url") == null || "".equals(propertyResolver.getProperty("url"))) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", propertyResolver.getProperty("databaseName"));
            config.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", propertyResolver.getProperty("serverName"));
        } else {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("url", propertyResolver.getProperty("url"));
        }
        config.addDataSourceProperty("user", propertyResolver.getProperty("username"));
        config.addDataSourceProperty("password", propertyResolver.getProperty("password"));

        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }


    @Bean
    public Hibernate4Module hibernate4Module() {
        return new Hibernate4Module();
    }
    }
```

whenever I run the application, spring throws a strange exception, telling that a bean cration fails

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
```

**the full output**

```
2016-05-03 14:35:27.844  INFO 28744 --- [           main] com.ben.batch.Application             : Starting Application on med with PID 28744 (/home/med/workplace/ben-batch/target/classes started by med in /home/med/workplace/ben-batch)
2016-05-03 14:35:27.875  INFO 28744 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@548ad73b: startup date [Tue May 03 14:35:27 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-05-03 14:35:28.403  INFO 28744 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'jobRepository': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=jobRepository; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.ModularBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=jobRepository; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/ModularBatchConfiguration.class]]
2016-05-03 14:35:28.403  INFO 28744 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'jobLauncher': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=jobLauncher; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.ModularBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=jobLauncher; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/ModularBatchConfiguration.class]]
2016-05-03 14:35:28.404  INFO 28744 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'transactionManager': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.ModularBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/ModularBatchConfiguration.class]]
2016-05-03 14:35:28.404  INFO 28744 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'jobExplorer': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=jobExplorer; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.ModularBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=jobExplorer; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/ModularBatchConfiguration.class]]
2016-05-03 14:35:28.554  INFO 28744 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2016-05-03 14:35:28.820  WARN 28744 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.stepScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details
2016-05-03 14:35:28.830  WARN 28744 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.jobScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details
2016-05-03 14:35:29.049  INFO 28744 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$77d3faef] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-05-03 14:35:29.065  INFO 28744 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionAttributeSource' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-05-03 14:35:29.073  INFO 28744 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionInterceptor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-05-03 14:35:29.076  INFO 28744 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-05-03 14:35:29.295  INFO 28744 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-05-03 14:35:29.421  INFO 28744 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-05-03 14:35:29.422  INFO 28744 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.15
2016-05-03 14:35:29.549  INFO 28744 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-05-03 14:35:29.550  INFO 28744 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1676 ms
2016-05-03 14:35:29.878  INFO 28744 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-05-03 14:35:29.881  INFO 28744 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-05-03 14:35:29.882  INFO 28744 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-05-03 14:35:29.922  INFO 28744 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Started.
2016-05-03 14:35:29.970  INFO 28744 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.getNetworkTimeout() is not yet implemented.)
2016-05-03 14:35:30.061  INFO 28744 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-05-03 14:35:30.067  INFO 28744 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-05-03 14:35:30.073  WARN 28744 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at com.ben.batch.Application.main(Application.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildBootstrapServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:186)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider$1.<init>(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 18 common frames omitted

2016-05-03 14:35:30.076  INFO 28744 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Close initiated...
2016-05-03 14:35:30.077  INFO 28744 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Closed.
2016-05-03 14:35:30.078  INFO 28744 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-05-03 14:35:30.083  WARN 28744 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'jobRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/ModularBatchConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' is defined)
2016-05-03 14:35:30.084 ERROR 28744 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
```

Any idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to use Hibernate when there is already an API provided?

Comment: I've asked the same question, they replied with the hibernate vs jdbcTemplate arguments

Comment: But why do you care what the underling mechanism is?  Especially since they both end up doing JDBC under the hood.

Comment: well after using hibernate for so long, it seems wrong when using sql queries on my oop code

Comment: But you aren't using SQL.  I'm saying use the APIs.  I'm encouraging this not because of the SQL vs Hibernate argument, but because you don't control the schema...we (Spring) does.  So if we change it, we'll update the API for you.  Otherwise, you now have an API that needs to evolve any time we change the schema.  Why would you not use the `JobExplorer` for what you need?